# Difficulty in Understanding Bicubic Image Interpolation

Tags: interpolation, bicubic

I need to write a MATLAB code for implementing three types of image interpolation : (i)nearest-neighbor,(ii) bi-linear, and (iii)bi-cubic.

Even after searching the Internet thoroughly ,including both videos and text, I am finding difficulties in understanding clearly the basic concepts of bi-cubic image interpolation.

What I basically need is a clear example of bi-cubic image interpolation, which will take input an image of specific dimensions and particular intensity values and then it will clearly explain the step-by-step computations to reach the finally zoomed or shrank image with particular intensity values.

I would be extremely obliged for any such example which will help me to understand the basic concepts clearly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hope this helps... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link..but I think I have already gone through the link. This page shows step-by-step calculations but does not explain them with a particular example.  I simply need a particular example of bi-cubic interpolation which will explain each step clearly. @ Mark Setchell